# What is the proper way to write a mobile app that updates itself by downloading data instead of doing an app store update?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I've seen several apps where the initial app is a few dozen megabytes but, once you start the app, they need to download "extra data." Sometimes this data is hundreds of megabytes (eg. The Simpsons Tapped Out).

What is the proper way to do this? I know that modifying the contents of your app is a no-no, as doing so will invalidate your app's signature. So, are you just supposed to write this data to the sdcard? Is Apple ok with apps that have no initial content of their own and need to download everything? I assume Android would be fine.

Also, if the data I need to download contains assets (such as images and even HTML files for web views), is there an easy way to keep these files from prying users?

Comment: Apple is allowing Apps to download in the document directory of your apps sandbox. You can not alter the app bundle on iOS so any files downloaded are placed in the document directory. Also you have cache directory for storing files which can be redownloaded by the app, since files in this directory can be removed if the device is running low on disk space. May app do this, can you image a news app with an AppStore update for every article that gets posted?

Comment: Well, sure. I wouldn't expect an app to download things that could be easily provided by a webservice. However, using the Simpsons example, they have periodic holiday updates where there are lots of new items, quests, graphics, etc. You wouldn't want to call a webservice for that type of info all the time. I assume the document directory for iOS is similar to an Android app writing files to the sdcard?